# How to remember Allah all the time?

Tags: quran

I just want to remember Allah all the time but i'm unable to because alot of other thinkings get enter into my mind so please tell me the way to think about Allah all the time???

Comment: I would strongly recommend you check the advice in our help centre pages on [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand the sorts of questions we encourage here; as-written, this looks like a vague open-ended call for opinions rather than a practical and answerable question.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this answer; tasawwuf is concerned with just this question, and a primer on it would be useful on this site. So far, there's not a single question about it on here, let alone a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

My teacher's advise was that we have to start the day with "niyaa" thinking that everything we will try to accomplish today is to get closer to Allah. So, just do your job/school/life with this thought in my mind. My dad's advise is to keep a "tasabih" with me in my pocket so whenever I put my hand in my pocket I remember that I have to do a bit of "dikr".